# Raspbian Reboot Hangs

Tags: raspbian, python

Having a bit of a problem on Raspbian Jesse. I have 2 switches which I use to shut down and restart my raspberry pi. Python does an `os.system ("sudo reboot")` and `os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")` on the tactile switch press. This works great in previous verson of raspbian on a pi 2 but on jesse on a pi 3, pressing the tactile switches which calls the os.system commands above just freeses my application and that is it. Also every now and then when rebooting or shutting down from the command line it gets stuck as per the attached image and just sits there.

[image: sudo reboot]

I then have to pull power. Although shutting down from gui or command line it does not happen every time but through my app it does.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to start. Dmesg gives me nothing neither does the kernel log. At least not from what i can see. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I tried switching to the systemd commands ie `sudo systemctl poweroff` and `sudo systemctl reboot` but the result seems to be the same.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a Pi Zero with the latest raspbian

Comment: Me three https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90798/jessie-lite-reboot-hang-on-rpi-3